# If condition for Woocommerce Parent categories and it's subcategories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, parent-child, categories

I want to display different design template for my shop **Music** categories and it's all sub categories compare to other categories design template.

For this i have added following if condition:

```
if (is_product_category( 'music' ))
{
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product-cubicles.php' );
} else 
{   
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); 
}
```

But above code only display new template for **Music** parent category not it's child categories.

So any one know solutions for this then please inform me.

Thanks,
Ketan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
if (is_product_category( 'music' ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( MUSIC_ID, get_queried_object()->term_id)
{
  wc_get_template( 'archive-product-cubicles.php' );
} else 
{   
wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' ); 
}
```

Replace **MUSIC_ID** with your own id of music category.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing parenthesis?